# Spring Session with Hazelcast 4

Tags: hazelcast, spring-session

I'm trying to upgrade to Hazelcast 4.0 in our Spring Boot 2.2.1 application.
We use the `@EnableHazelcastHttpSession` annotation, which pulls in `HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration`, which pulls in [`HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/session/hazelcast/HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository.html) from the [`spring-session-hazelcast`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-hazelcast.html) jar.
However, this class won't compile because it imports Hazelcast's `IMap` which has moved to a different package in Hz 4.0.

Is there any way to fix this so that Spring Session works with Hazelcast 4?

Comment: I don't think it is supported yet. I have raised a github issue. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1584
Do you want to contribute? I can help you in review process.

Comment: There's a similar problem with the health check (because Endpoint has moved to a new package). I can fix it by copying Spring's HazelcastHealthIndicator into my own source tree.

Comment: Despited the ticket created by @Mesut has been resolved spring-session-hazelcast 2.3.1.RELEASE (which is the latest version right now) it's still giving the same error with Hazelcast 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository into my own source code, changed the import from `com.hazelcast.core.IMap` to `com.hazelcast.map.IMap`, and swapped the sessionListenerId from String to UUID. If I keep it in the same package, then it loads my class instead of the one in the jar, and everything compiles and works fine.

Edit: We no longer get the SessionExpiredEvent, so something's not quite right, but manual testing shows us that our sessions do time out and force the user to log in again, even across multiple servers.

Comment: Moving the class solves the class not found but not the cause, when doing so it's using Hazelcast 4 code with old HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository from Version 3 it will have unpredicted behaviour. Fix this by using Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error, you must look that the session repository is created by HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration, in the class it checks wich version of hazelcast is in the classpath, when hazelcast4 is true then it instantiates Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository that doesn't use 'com.hazelcast.core.IMap' and you don't get the class not found exception.

Code of class HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration

```
@Bean
public FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<?> sessionRepository() {
    return (FindByIndexNameSessionRepository)(hazelcast4 ? this.createHazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository() : this.createHazelcastIndexedSessionRepository());
}
```

**Remove the usage of HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository replace it with Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository or remove the code and let spring autoconfiguration do the job by HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration**